# Prevent gmail app android rendering mobile HTML emails

Tags: css, html, gmail, media-queries

It is pretty disappointing that the Android Gmail app which is made by Google can not support standard media queries in 2015.

Does anyone have an alternative solution to prevent the app from showing some of my mobile queries and ignoring multiple column queries to display in a block, and just keep it at 600px like a desktop view?

Comment: I would like to add the fact that media queries are not readed by Outlook online too.

Comment: Okay when I run my email's through litmus they work perfectly fine in all the email clients available to test, comes to the gmail app on android and it all breaks.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you're doing? It's easier for us to give you workarounds if you show us some code.

Comment: Your question's title (and therefore your whole question) is incomprehensible. Please edit it. Feel free to tag me afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

E-mails should be coded all with inline styling.. sadly.

Comment: You mean if I copy n paste the rich result of a document that has CSS in its head, it won't work?